# What should I return when modelstate is invalid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, modelstate, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view in a layout file, my partial view has a form and some server side validation. when my form is submitted and modelstate is invalid what should I return?

something is bold here:

1) I don't want to use javascript

2) I want to show modelstat errors in client side

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in that place, where you want to display your errors

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to behave like a partial view:

```
return PartialView();
```

This posts the original model back with the current model state. You can use `@Html.ValidationSummary()` to display the errors as stated by @FSou1.